# Не получается использовать дату в String.format

Tags: java

Пытаюсь послать дату в `DateTimePicker` через Silenium.
Использую следующий код

```
public void setDataDateTimePicker(String cssSelector, Date date) {
    System.out.println("Set date and time to calendar");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript(String.format("$('%s').datepicker('setDate', '%t)", cssSelector, date));
}
```

Но `String.format` почему то не понимает `%t`. Как будто ошибка по синтаксису

Comment: Может, не хватает закрывающейся кавычки `'%t'`?

Comment: Не то. Все равно не дает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите текст ошибки (добавьте его прямо в вопрос).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%t` - это только префикс, указывающий, что будет форматироваться объект, относящийся к дате/времени (см. документацию [Formatter::Date/Time Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt)).

В качестве объекта могут приниматься любые типы, использующиеся для представления даты/времени, т.е. `long`, `Long`, `Date`, `Calendar` и классы из пакета `java.time`, реализующие интерфейс `TemporalAccessor`, такие как `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` и т.д.

Нужно дополнительно указать вид преобразования, например:

- `yyyy-MM-dd`: стандартный формат даты ISO-8601: `"%tY-%tm-%td"` или `"%tF"`
- `mm/dd/yy`: `"%tm/%td/%ty"` или `"%tD"`

Примеры использования:

```java
System.out.printf("Set date and time to calendar: %tF %n", new Date());
System.out.printf("Set date and time to calendar: %tD %n", LocalDate.now());
```

```
Set date and time to calendar: 2023-02-02 
Set date and time to calendar: 02/02/23
```